# How to make DRF's AutoSchema include a base url?

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to implement API Documentation using DRF's Open API AutoSchema + Swagger UI.

What I want to do is specify a base url so that the schema and swagger only display the resource (endpoint).

In my project urlpatterns I have:

```
path('api/', include('api.urls')),
path('openapi/', get_schema_view(
    title="Diakonia API",
    description="API for food bank Diakonia",
    version="1.0.0",
    urlconf='api.urls',
), name='openapi-schema'),
path('swagger-ui/', TemplateView.as_view(
    template_name='swagger-ui.html',
    extra_context={'schema_url': 'openapi-schema'}
), name='swagger-ui')
```

This is what my schema looks like:

[image]

And this is how it's displaying:
[image]

But, when I "Try it out" it's giving me an error because it tries to make the request to: `localhost:8080/institutions` when it should be `localhost:8080/api/institutions`.

If I add the url property in get_schema_view() like this: `url='/api/'` then IT WORKS, BUT, the endpoints display the `api` and that is part of the base url, not the resource:
[image]

Comment: I don't think `api` being the base url means it doesn't not display it in the url path. So the second version actually looks like how it is supposed to

Comment: But all my resources are under /api/, so, the second version is too redundant. What if my api was versioned? Then I'd had /api/v1/ for every endpoint which makes it less readable.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [drf-spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

once you installed and configured with your app, you can use a setting variable to reach what you need:

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
# ... your other settings
'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX': '/api/',
}
```